# how to prevent urlencoding in post body form while still using urlencoded content-type header?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

whenever I send a post request, the post body always get encoded (white spaces) are converted to (+) like in this picture
[image]

and I always thought this is uncontrollable behavior if I used the header

```
contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
```

till I encountered this form, see how the form body didn't get encoded

[image]

although the content type in the header is

[image]

please tell me **HOW** they get the form not encoded although they used the url encoding header in the request ?:( 
I can't understand this with my own , I tried using sending the request with ajax using jquery and XMLHttpRequest but it is the same result, gets encoded whenever I use the header `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8`

the page is [here](http://eservices.mci.gov.sa/eservices/Industry/IndustrialDirectoryByProducts.aspx) if you needed to inspect it, but it is in Arabic language and the form I mean is submitted like in this picture

[image]

Comment: Tools are your nemesis.  The request might be correctly urlencoded, maybe using `%20` instead of `+` as spaces (that would still be valid encoding), but the tool decodes it as spaces and displays it.  What tool are you using to perform the debugging?  I'd suggest catching the request in something like `tamper data` or `wireshark` which allow you to define **how you see** the captured data.

Comment: @grochmal it is Firefox developer tools. OK , then how do I encode the URL spaces to `%20` instead of `+`?